# Who will help me against Allah if I drove them away?

Tags: rhetorical-questions

> Who will help me against Allah if I drove them away?

This rhetorical question is a translation of an Arabic / Quranic text that performs denial where a prophet denies that his people will protect him from Allah in case he drives the believers away.

Do you find any denial function in the English rhetorical question?

Comment: Can you please provide in which chapter (surah) and verse (ayah) in Quran that was mentioned?

Comment: Surah Hud, verse 30

Comment: I'm afraid your interpretation is not _totally_ correct. Here's how they interpret it: **And O my people, who would protect me from Allah if I drove them away? Then will you not be reminded?** [Source](https://www.quran.com/11)

Answer (score 2):

Neither denial nor assertion is implied by the question itself. The answer implied by a rhetorical question depends on the context. In this context, it's negative:

> Who will help me [*context: defy Allah*]? . . . ***Nobody!***.

But in another context the same question might imply a positive answer:

> Who will help me [*context: eat this cake*]? . . . ***Everybody!***